# Why doesn't v-show displayed when I go back to the previous step?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, show

I have an SAP in VUE that consists of a form in 4 steps.
When submit in the first step button and redirect to second step, if I return to first step the last component is stopped showing, in spite of being shown before changing the component.
this is my template

```html
   <input
      type="text"
      id="animalName"
      ref="animalName"
      v-model="animalFormInfo.name"
      @keypress="onChangeName($event)"
      @keyup="onChangeName($event)"
      />
      <div class="loader-spinner" v-if="loading">
        <app-loader>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div v-show="isNameCompleted">
  <div class="from-group">
    <h1 class="title">
      For
      <span>{{this.formInfo.name}}</span>, you have:
    </h1>
    <div class="list-services">
      <div
        class="column-service"
        v-for="estimation in filteredEstimation"
        v-bind:key="estimation.name"
      >
        <div>{{estimation.name}}</div>
        <div>{{estimation.description}}</div>
        <div>{{estimation.price.toString().replace(".", ",")}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button-line" v-show="isLoaderFinished"></div>
<div class="forward" v-show="isLoaderFinished">
  <div class="forward-button">
    <button
      ref="submit"
      v-bind:disabled="!isFormCompleted"
      type="submit"
      @click="navigateToCreate"
    >
      SEND INFO
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and below the data and the method in which I control the load of the components

```js
data() {
  return {
    step: 1,
    isFormCompleted: false,
    isBreedSelected: false,
    isNameCompleted: false,
    loading: false,
    isLoaderFinished: false,
    myTimeout: 0
  };
},
methods:{
  onChangeName(event) {
    if (this.myTimeout >= 0 && event) {
      clearTimeout(this.myTimeout);
      this.loading = true;
      this.isNameCompleted = false;
    }
    this.myTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.isNameCompleted = true;
      const typedAnimalName = event.target._value;
      this.capitalizeAnimalName(typedAnimalName);
      this.loading = false;
      this.isLoaderFinished = true;
      this.isFormCompleted = true;
      setTimeout(() => (this.$refs.scrolled_3.focus()), 10);
    }, 2200);
  },

  capitalizeAnimalName(typedAnimalName) {
    var splitAnimalName = typedAnimalName.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < splitAnimalName.length; i++) {
      splitAnimalName[i] = splitAnimalName[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitAnimalName[i].substring(1);
    } 
    return this.animalName = splitAnimalName.join(' ');
  },
},
```

Once I reach step 2 and return to step 1 only the info is shown until the input with id "animalName".
What am I doing wrong?
Is there any reason why when loading the first component it follows the logic and shows them and once I go to the next one they disappear?

thank you all for your time and help in advance

Comment: `<div v-show="this.isNameCompleted">` won't work. it's the equivalent of `this.this.isNameCompleted`, which will always return a falsy value (or an error)

Comment: Don't use "this" in the template. It probably causes your problem.

Comment: @Daniel I have corrected it and it still behaves the same way, in step one it is shown correctly and the moment I go to the second step and return to the first one it stops showing

Comment: @BülentAkgül I have removed all references to this in the template and it still fails me only that element, I have other previous v-shows that when I return to the original component are shown without problem

Comment: can you list the (full) version of vue you're using? is it v2.6 + or 3?

Comment: @Daniel     "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the state of the component is not persistent.

There are multiple solutions for this.

### 1. Manage state globally with `Vuex`

This is probably the default, or most common way of handling this kind of situation. Instead of storing the data in the component, you use this library to manage the state. Most likely you can just implement vuex in your project and not read on. It's a solid choice with too many upsides to list.

### 2. Encapsulate form state in the parent component.

Instead of managing the state within the step component, you can create the state for the relevant data inside the parent object.

example:

```html
<Step2
  v-if="step === 2"
  :formData="formData"
  :updateFormData="updateFormData"
  :nextStep="() => gotoStep(3)"
></Step2>
```

The idea is that the `Step2` component would have the data passed in through `formData` prop. And any time that data changes, `updateFormData` function is called with the new data. You could even simplify it by utilizing the `v-model`.

### 3. DIY store

If you're using Vue js 2 (>= 2.6, < 3), you can do this with `observable`

#### Vue 2.6+

create a `store.js` file

```
import Vue from "vue";
export const store = Vue.observable({
  step: 1,
  isFormCompleted: false,
  isBreedSelected: false,
  isNameCompleted: false,
  loading: false,
  isLoaderFinished: false,
});
```

Then you can call your `store.js` from any component, and if you assign it to `this` in the `beforeCreate` hook, you can use it just like data (`this.store.isFormCompleted` in script, `store.isFormCompleted` in template)

```
import { store} from 'store.js';
//...
  beforeCreate(){
    this.store = store;
  }
```

if you want to skip the extra `store.`, you could even destructure the store object.

#### Vue 3

Similar to the other one there, but use a `reactive()` (or multiple `ref()`). Let me know if you want me to expand on this.

Comment: I already had the store declared, I changed the conditions of the v-show to the data stored in the store and it works perfectly. Thank you very much, I was stack.

Answer (score 1):

If each step is its own component, you can use the `keep-alive` component to cache the components and their state, so that when you switch between them, their state is retained. I would personally prefer that over using Vuex in this case, since it's much simpler.

```
<keep-alive>
    <step-1-component v-if="step === 1"></step-1-component>
    <step-2-component v-if="step === 2"></step-2-component>
    <step-3-component v-if="step === 3"></step-3-component>
</keep-alive>
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Answer (score 0):

It is so because the component is re-rendering when you go back to the first page, so all the default states will take effect. Try saving your states with [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) so that all components will be controlled by the state from the store.